# How to find the closest point (in a grid) to UILongGestureRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app with a simple grid. (I have an array of `NSValue`s containing the `CGPoint` of the center point of each grid space.)

The user can touch anywhere on screen, and I want to know how I can find the grid space that is closest to the users touch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding distance to the closest point in a point cloud on an uniform grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735134/finding-distance-to-the-closest-point-in-a-point-cloud-on-an-uniform-grid)

Comment: Are the grid spaces all the same size? To be clear, you want to find the closest point, on the closest edge, on the closest rectangle (that is a single grid space) to the users touch?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pythagorean theorem. Distance to point = sqrt((p2.x - p1.x)^2 + (p2.y - p1.y)^2). If p1 is the point of the touch, use this equation, p2 being each point on your grid, and find the largest distance

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below method to do this:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {<br>
        id hitView = [self hitTest:currentTouchPoint withEvent:event];<br>
        if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[RDWord class]]) { // basically find the type of view you  
                                                       // want over here                              
        }

}
```

OR you can use as below :

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
UIView *hitView = [self hitTest:location withEvent:event];
```

Comment: Thanks! But I know the location of the touch, I want to know how to compare the locations to find out which is grid is closest to the user touch!